# Mixed-effects model: Help with model specification

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to specify a mixed-effects model and would appreciate your help:

The total cohort consists of two subcohorts; the first subcohort is part of a controlled trial, in which half of the patients (PATIENT) received a certain treatment (TRTM), the other half not; the second subcohort is derived from an observational study, again some received the treatment, some not.

The outcome of interest is a parameter, for which 1 baseline value (VALUE_BL) and 1 follow-up value (VALUE_FU) are available. In the first subcohort, the duration of treatment (DUR) is the same for all patients; due the observational character it is unequal in the second subcohort.

We consider VALUE_BL to be associated with a third continuous variable (VAR3, only measured at baseline); and VALUE_FU (and the change compared to VALUE_BL) to be associated with treatment, treatment duration and VAR3. There is only a small overlap of the distribution of VAR3 across the two subcohorts.

**The questions we have on our data set are:**

1. Is there a effect of TRTM on VALUE_FU and its change to VALUE_BL?
2. Is this effect different depending on VAR3?

**My ideas so far:**

1. A DUR*TRTM interaction as fixed effect accounts for different effect of TRTM depending on its DUR.
2. A random intercept for PATIENT is needed.
3. A random slope for DUR is needed.
4. Both a fixed effect and a random intercept (maybe also a random slope) for VAR3 is needed.

**My questions:**

1. Is this the proper analysis strategy?
2. Both DUR and VAR3 would be part of the fixed effect section and of the random effects section. Is this appropriate?
3. Do you have other hints to improve the analysis?